# Modify Azure B2C sign in V1 policy/user flow minimum password length restriction

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

We have a special case where, for our Azure B2C users, we set the *forceChangePasswordOnNextLogin* property for a user account when creating it. For logging in, the user signs in through a SignIn V1 User Flow, which allows the user to change their password on their initial login.

We now want to change the password complexity to allow 10 characters instead of Azure's default 8. Is there a way to accomplish this without the use of custom policies or v2 user flows (since the sign in v2 user flow dos not allow a user to change their password)?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Let me describe our workflow. This is what we have right now:

- I create a B2C user and with an initial temporary password. The user is created through the Graph API and I set *forceChangePasswordOnNextLogin* to true.
- I send the user this temporary password
- The user logs himself/herself in using the sign in v1 user flow/policy
- The policy forces the user to change his/her password

So far, this is working just fine. However, we now want that when the user is forced to change his/her password, they do so with custom password security requirements (minimum of 10 characters required).

Comment: Yep, forgot to do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use custom policies. We never recommend sending passwords in emails either. Look at our invite sample, since your moving to custom policies it’s worth implementing.

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/invite/README.md

Comment: We did consider custom policies but were hoping to have a solution from Microsoft itself for this. After correspondence with Microsoft, internet research and your answer however, it seems custom policies is the only viable way forward.

Answer (score 0):

The B2C sign in v1 user flow/policy are not applicable When the user is created using Graph API. The User is created in Azure AD Tenant when creating through Graph API. After `forceChangePasswordOnNextLogin` is set `True` and When the use tries to set the new password then it uses the Azure AD default password policy.

If you want to change the Default Azure AD password policy you can try with [custom password policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/password-policy#create-a-custom-password-policy)

Comment: But this doesn't change the password requirements for the initial password change. I will edit the question to clarify the workflow.